# Cakephp - Cannot commit transaction - rollback()

Tags: php, database, cakephp, transactions, cakephp-3.x

I have a little problem. I have a Cakephp 3.6 project. All work fine, but when I want to delete a record in one controller show my a error.

**Cannot commit transaction - rollback() has been already called in the nested transaction**
Cake\Database\Exception\NestedTransactionRollbackException

Cake\ORM\Table->delete
APP/Controller\NewsController.php, line 131

This is my **delete** action in NewsController.php

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $news = $this->News->get($id);
    if ($this->News->delete($news)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The news has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The news could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

And the error is highlighted on **if ($this->News->delete($news)) {**

What can I do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default all deletes happen within a transaction. How about you disable the transaction with the `atomic`?

Something likes

`$this->News->delete($news, ['atomic' => false]);`

Comment: If work, pls mark as accept answer that can help other people who have same problem like you :)